# Is there any way to rgister multiple users in ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

I have to add 10k users in ejabberd.Is there any way to rgister multiple users in ejabberd?

Answer (score 1):

I asume you have in ejabberd configured the default authentication method: internal.

If you already have the accounts in a database (LDAP, SQL, other), maybe you can [connect ejabberd to them](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/), instead of registering the accounts in the internal ejabberd database?

Or you can write an [external script](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/#external-script) in any language that checks account credentials against your database, and tell ejabberd to check accounts using that script.

If they are simply test accounts, you can use some registration tool, for example [jab_simul](https://github.com/badlop/jab_simul) that simply registers account names test_0001, test_0002, ...

If you really are using the internal authentication method in ejabberd, there are two ways to register it:

A) using In-Band Registration as defined in XMPP, using a XMPP client, XMPP bot or XMPP library.

B) Another method is to use the [register](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#register) API command provided by ejabberd.

An easy way to call this API is in the command line:

```
$ ejabberdctl register joe localhost somepAss
User joe@localhost successfully registered
```

However, ejabberdctl starts a small erlang each time, so that would be very slow for registering 10k accounts.
Check other [possible interfaces to call ejabberd's API](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/#understanding-ejabberd-commands).

Comment: Thanks @Badlop for your value able reply . Currently I am using mongodb database which stores the user data . I have to implement ejabberd in my application . For new added user I have used Method B. But I have to migrate my exiting users to ejabberd.

Comment: The only information you need from your mongodb database to ejabberd is the account authentication (username, domain, password)? Then you could try to write an extauth script. That way, ejabberd asks your database when a user tries to login, and later stores all information in its internal database. That way you have one single list of accounts (in mongodb), the passwords are only stored in mongodb, etc.